# Why TabBar View hides under Tab Bar?

Tags: android, flutter, tabview

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZgzk.jpg)When I scroll my screen flexible space collapses which is fine but as I scroll my tab bar view a part of It moves under tab bar even if I don't add scroll in Tab Bar view. I am new to flutter, this is my first project. Please help me with this issue. Also I am new to stack overflow. BTW I have to add these lines because stack overflow is giving me this error "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." :) :)

### [Heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YSsY.png) ##return Scaffold(

```
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Author"),),
      body: NestedScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool boxIsScrolled){
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              leading: Container(),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              forceElevated: boxIsScrolled,
              bottom: TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
              tabs: [
                Tab(child: Row(mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,children:[Icon(Icons.photo_sharp, color: Colors.black,),SizedBox(width: 10.0,),Text("Posts", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)],),),
                Tab(child: Row(mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,children:[Icon(Icons.dashboard_rounded, color: Colors.black,),SizedBox(width: 10.0,),Text("Courses", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)],),),
                ],
              ),
              flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
                child: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
                  background: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 45.0,
                                child: author.photo_url == null ? Image.asset("assets/user.png") : imageUrl == null ? CircularProgressIndicator():
                                      ClipRRect(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(83.0),
                                        child: Image(
                                          image: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
                                          width: 140,
                                          height: 140,
                                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                        ),
                                      )),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: [
                                    Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                      children: [
                                        Text("Followers", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 19.0)),
                                        SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
                                        Text("0", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 18.0)),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                      children: [
                                        Text("Posts", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 19.0)),
                                        SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
                                        Text("0", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 18.0)),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                      children: [
                                        Text("Courses", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 19.0)),
                                        SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
                                        Text("0", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 18.0)),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 8, 0, 0),
                          child: Text("${author.name}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, letterSpacing: 1.0),),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 0, 0),
                          child: Text("${author.qualification}", style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.0),),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 0, 0),
                          child: Text("${author.profession}", style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.0),),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 0),
                          child: Container(
                            width: deviceWidth,
                            child: RaisedButton.icon(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              label: Text(followedAuthorsID.contains(author.id) ? "Following" : "Follow", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, letterSpacing: 0.5),),
                              icon: Icon(followedAuthorsID.contains(author.id) ? Icons.check_box : Icons.person_add, color: Colors.white,),
                              onPressed: (){
                                followAuthor(author, followedAuthorsID.contains(author.id));
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Divider(height: 40,color: Colors.black,),
                      ]),
                ),
              ),
              expandedHeight: 305,
            )
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            GridView.count(
              childAspectRatio: 1,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              children: [
                Container(color: Colors.red,),
                Container(color: Colors.green,),
                Container(color: Colors.red,),
                Container(color: Colors.green,),
              ],
            ),
            // ListView(
            //   children : [
            //     SizedBox(height: 100),
            //     Center(child: Text("No Posts Added", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 22, letterSpacing: 0.5),)),
            ListView(
                children : [
                  SizedBox(height: 100,),
                  Center(child: Text("No Courses Added", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 22, letterSpacing: 0.5),)),
                  SizedBox(height: 25),
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 45,
                    child: Icon(Icons.dashboard_rounded, size: 35,),
                  ),
                ]
            ),
          ],
        ),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Please share the screenshot or video

Comment: @Kudos There is link of screenshot at the top